# SQL IN function is not working in jasper report

Tags: mysql, sql, jasper-reports

my query is looks like this

```
 SELECT * FROM INVOICE WHERE date IN ($P{date})
```

i pass my date list as a String to the "date" parameter with comma. But i'm getting data only for the first date in the list.

Comment: Did you get the query generated by engine? Did you check this query?

Comment: `SQL IN function is not working in jasper report` - Operator IN is definitely working well at JasperReports

Comment: Yes i checked. I'm getting data only for the first date in the parameter list..

Comment: Found the solution - SELECT * FROM INVOICE WHERE date IN ($P!{date})

Answer (score 0):

Split the date field like this:

```
$P{date}.toString().split(",")
```